# Bounding $(\int_{S^1}\left|\partial_r u(r\omega)\right|^2 d\omega)^{1/2}$ with $(\iint \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2+2s}} dxdy)^{1/2} $?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

The following inequality is trivially true
$$\left(\int_{S^1}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r\omega)\right|^2 d\omega\right)^{1/2} \le \left(\int_{S^1}\left|\nabla u(r\omega)\right|^2 d\omega\right)^{1/2} $$
Here $\omega \in S^1$, $r \ge 1$, and $u$ is a smooth decaying function.

Would it be possible to replace the right-hand side with the fractional seminorm $$\left(\int\int \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2+2s}} dxdy \right)^{1/2}, $$ $s \in (0,1)$ in some way?

Comment: One may try to guess here as to what $u$, $r$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r\omega)$, and $s$ are, but they need to be specified nonetheless.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**. If $\gamma>s$, then Holder continuous functions $C^{0,\gamma}\subset W^{s,p}(B^n)$ belong to the fractional Sobolev space on any $n$-dimensional ball. Since Holder continuous function need not be differentiable, there is no way you can estimate its derivative. This also shows that even if you work with smooth functions you cannot get such an estimate since by approximation it would pass to the Holder functions.

In fact an opposite inequality is true: In general we can estimates the integral of $|\nabla u|^p$ on the ball by the fractional Sobolev integral of  $u$ on the boundary for $s>1-1/p$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you write down what is precisely the opposite inequality?

Comment: @Zac. I will do it later. I am busy now. If you do not see my answer by tomorrow send me a reminder.

Comment: Hi. Could you write down what is the opposite inequality?

Comment: "Too busy, remind me later," and then ghost someone.  Lamest QED ever @PiotrHajlasz :p